# SQL Create View ,Show view,Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, view

sql question,  I created a view, but problems comes from when 
I tried to show the view using select * from the view.

```
CREATE VIEW YearByYearSalesDelta as 
WITH temp 
    as (select SalesPersonID,YEAR(DueDate) as SaleYear, SUM(SubTotal) as Total 
        from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
        group by SalesPersonID, year(DueDate)
        )
    select NewYear.SalesPersonID,
        OldYear.SaleYear AS OldYear, 
        NewYear.SaleYear as NewYear,
        NewYear.Total-OldYear.Total as Delta
    from temp AS OldYear 
        JOIN temp AS NewYear  on   NewYear.SalesPersonID=OldYear.SalesPersonID
                AND NewYear.SaleYear-1=OldYear.SaleYear

SELECT * FROM dbo.YearByYearSalesDelta
```

message shows

```
**Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure YearYearSalesDelta, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.**
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the batch separator GO after the view

```
CREATE VIEW YearByYearSalesDelta as 
WITH temp 
    as (select SalesPersonID,YEAR(DueDate) as SaleYear, SUM(SubTotal) as Total 
        from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
        group by SalesPersonID, year(DueDate)
        )
    select NewYear.SalesPersonID,
        OldYear.SaleYear AS OldYear, 
        NewYear.SaleYear as NewYear,
        NewYear.Total-OldYear.Total as Delta
    from temp AS OldYear 
        JOIN temp AS NewYear  on   NewYear.SalesPersonID=OldYear.SalesPersonID
                AND NewYear.SaleYear-1=OldYear.SaleYear

GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.YearByYearSalesDelta
```

Comment: Or properly terminate statements using `;` https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons